# Size class in a UIPageView Container canges to unspecified

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios9, size-classes

I have a nested view inside a view with a UIPageViewDelegate. The first view loads fine (SizeClass wCompact hRegular), but the newly created ViewController after swiping have UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular value.

This - of course - scrambles my layout. BTW: I do not change the orientation.

Q: Is there a way to force to change to a certain Size class? 
Any idea whats the problem here? Only portrait mode is allowed in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation this appears to be a bug, which was introduced in iOS 9